# Finding Big O of the Harmonic Series

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

Prove that

```
1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/n is O(log n). 
Assume n = 2^k
```

I put the series into the summation, but I have no idea how to tackle this problem. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 78, accepted):

This follows easily from a simple fact in Calculus:

[image]

and we have the following inequality:

[image]

Here we can conclude that S = 1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/n is both Ω(log(n)) and O(log(n)), thus it is Ɵ(log(n)), the bound is actually tight.

Comment: Thanks! My professor said we shouldn't use calculus for this one. Any tips on how to solve it using discrete math?

Comment: For your purpose (i.e. proving the `O(log(n))` upper bound), you only need to argue the leftmost inequality holds (i.e. `1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/(n+1) <= ln(n)`), you can argue this by mathematical induction. (*Hint*: argue that we have `1/(n+1) <= log(n+1) - log(n) = log(1+1/n)` using Taylor's expansion or otherwise)

Answer (score 19):

Here's a formulation using Discrete Mathematics:

[image]
So, H(n) = O(log n)

Answer (score 0):

If the problem was changed to :

`1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + ... + 1/n`

series can now be written as:

`1/2^0 + 1/2^1 + 1/2^2 + ... + 1/2^(k)`

How many times loop will run?  `0` to `k = k + 1` times.From both series, we can see `2^k = n`. Hence `k = log (n)`. So, the number of times it runs = `log(n) + 1 = O(log n)`.