# What will be time complexity of the following?

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity

What will be time complexity of the following function?

How can be the time complexity of inner loop be log(n)?
it is given that the inner loop executes n/i times for each value of i.its running time is n*∑(from i=1 to n){n/i}.. and that i dnt get it

```
fucntion(n)
{ 
  for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
  {
    for(int j=1;j<=n;j+=i)
    {
      printf("*");
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: What does 1ogn mean?

Answer (score 1):

In the first run of inner loop, we will loop *n* times. The second time we will skip every other number, so we loop *n*/2 times, then *n*/3 times, etc. This continues until the final loop where we go *n*/*n* = 1 pass through the loop.

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905118/finding-big-o-of-the-harmonic-series), 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/*n* is O(log n). Since we are doing *n* times that, the resulting complexity is O(n log n).