# What is the time complexity of this pseudocode?

Tags: algorithm, function, loops, math, time-complexity

This is pseudocode. I tried to calculate the time complexity of this function as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35326140/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-my-function) said. It should be like:

```
n + n/3 + n/9 + ...
```

Maybe the time complexity is something like `O(nlog(n))` I guess? Or the `log(n)` should be `log(n)` **base 3**? Someone said the time complexity is *O(n)*, which is totally unacceptable for me.

```
j = n
while j >= 1 {
    for i = 1 to j {
        x += 1
    }
    j /= 3
}
```

Comment: Just sum the geometric series.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Just like this `n + n/3 + n/9 + ...`? But this is not O(n).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The algorithm will run in:

> n + n/3 + n/9 + ... = [series](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100321112000AAdiCRy) ~= O(3/2 * n) = O(n)

since 3/2 is a *constant*. Here the k-th loop will run in n/3<sup>k</sup> steps.

---

Please notice the crucial difference from the linked question, where the outer loop runs `n` times and that is fixed.