# Why does this algorithm run in O(n log n)?

Tags: big-o

We're supposed to "consider the following algorithm, which operates on an array A[1 . . n] of integers."

```
for i in [1 . . n] do
A[i] ← 0
for i in [1 . . n] do
    j ← i
    while j ≤ n do
        A[j] ← A[j] + 1
        j ← j + i
```

The assignment asks us to demonstrate that this algorithm runs in O(n log n).

The first loop is quite clearly going to add n to the run time, which would simply be dropped.

The second nested loops will run faster than a pure O(n^2) algorithm, since the while loop doesn't always run n times. When i = 1 it goes n times,  i = 2 it will run n-1 times, all the way up to i = n where it will run once.

But, using the same method as Gauss summing the integers between 1 and 100, we can see that the while loop will run an average of (n+1)/2 times. Multiply by n for the for loop, and we get to (n^2 + n)/2, which can be simplified down to O(n^2), not O(n log n)

How does this result in an O(n log n) running time?

Comment: Your description of the running time of the while loop is incorrect -- it runs floor(n/i) times. So when i == 2 it will run floor(n/2) times, when i == 3, it will run floor(n/3) times.  When i > n/2 (half the time) it will only run once.

Comment: To be more clear: it's `j + i`, not `j + 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the following:

```
for i in [1 . . n] do
    j ← i
    while j ≤ n do
        A[j] ← A[j] + 1
        j ← j + i
```

Each time, `j` is incremented with `+i`, not `+1`. As such, the first `while loop` while be iterated `n` times, then `n/2`, then `n/3`... up to `n/n`.

Ignoring integer rounding, we can write this in the following format:
`n(1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/n)`.

It seems that we are dealing with an harmonic serie, with an additional multiplication by `n`. Some more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905118/finding-big-o-of-the-harmonic-series) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35326405/11979706). This would be `O(n log n)`.