# Time complexity for the loop

Tags: time-complexity

The outer loop executes n times while the inner loop executes ? So the total time is n*something.

**Do i need to learn summation,if yes then any book to refer?**

```
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) 
  for(int j=1;j<=n;j+=i)
    printf("*");
```

Comment: How many times will the `printf()` run, given a particular value of `n`? That's the time complexity of this pair of nested loops.

Comment: @OllieJones So you are saying for a given value k, the time complexity will be O(k).Lets say n=5, inner loop executes for 5 time for i=1, iterating i to 2,inner loop executes 3 times, now i=3 inner loop executes 2 times and i=4 inner loop executes 2 times. It varies with i.

Comment: I think it prints floor(n/1) + floor(n/2) + ... + floor(n/n) times.

Comment: The running time looks like a harmonic number to me.  This [Math Stack Exchange article](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52572/do-harmonic-numbers-have-a-closed-form-expression) seems to say that there is no closed form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the time complexity of that is `O(n*log(n))`. Here is why:

Let us pick some arbitrary natural number i and see how many steps the inner loop takes for this given i. Well for this i, you are going from j=1 to j<=n with a jump of i in between. So basically you are doing this summation many steps:

```
summation =  1 + (1+i) + (1+2i) + ... (1+ki)
```

where k is the largest integer such that 1+ki <= n. That is, k is the number of steps and this is what we want to solve for. Well we can solve for k in the equality resulting in `k <= (n-1)/i` and thus `k = ⌊(n-1)/i⌋`. That is, k is the floor function/integer division of `(n-1)/i`. Since we are dealing with time complexities, this floor function doesn't matter so we will just say `k = n/i` for simplicity. This is the number of steps that the inner loop will take for a given i. So we basically need to add all these for i = 1 to i <= n.

So numsteps will be this addition:

```
numsteps = n/1 + n/2 + n/3 + ... n/n
         = n(1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... 1+n)
```

So we need to find the sum of 1 + 1/2 + ... 1/n to finish this. There is actually no good closed form for this sum but it is on the order of `ln(n)`. You can read more about this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496116/is-there-a-partial-sum-formula-for-the-harmonic-series). You can also guess this since the `integral from 1 to n of 1/x is ln(n)`. Again, since we are dealing with time complexity, we can just use ln(n) to represent its complexity. Thus we have:

```
numsteps = n(ln(n))
```

And so the time complexity is `O(n*log(n))`.

Edit: My bad, i was calculating the sum :P

Answer (score 4):

This question can be approached by inspection:

```
n = 16

i  |  j values         | # terms
1  |  1, 2, ..., 16    | n
2  |  1, 3, 5, ..., 16 | n / 2
.. |  ..               | n / 3
16 |  16               | n / n
```

In the above table, `i` is the outer loop value, and `j values` show the iterations of the inner loop.  By inspection, we can see that the loops will take `n * (1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/n)` steps.  This is a bounded harmonic series.  As [this Math Stack Exchange article](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52572/do-harmonic-numbers-have-a-closed-form-expression) shows, there is no closed form for the above expression in terms of `n`.  However, as [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905118/finding-big-o-of-the-harmonic-series) shows, there is an upper bound of `O(n*ln(n))`.

So, the running time for your two loops is `O(n*ln(n))`.