# What is the time complexity of the code below?

Tags: time-complexity

```
sum =0;

            for (int i=1; i<n; i++) {

              for (int j=1; j< n/i; j++) {

                sum = sum +j;

              }

            }
```

In the above outer loop , The variable **i** runs from 1 to n, thus making complexity of outer loop as O(n).
This explains the **n** part of O(n logn) complexity.

But for the outer part when we see then j runs from 1 to n/i, meaning whenever i is 1 , the complexity is **n** so i guess the inner time complexity should also be **O(n)**.

Making the total time Complexity as O(n*n)=O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

This is what you can do using Sigma notation:

[image]

With H_{n-1} is the harmonic function:

[Finding Big O of the Harmonic Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905118/finding-big-o-of-the-harmonic-series)