# what will be the time complexity (in bigO notation)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

I am not able to calculate the time complexity of this program.

```
`const int n=1e6+5;
 int prime[n];
 void pre()
 {
    prime[1]=1;
    for(int i=2;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(!prime[i])
        {
            for(int j=2;i*j<n;j++)
            {
                 prime[i*j]=1;
            }
         }
     }
 }`
```

can you tell what is the time complexity of this program in terms of big O notation

Comment: Looks like the sieve of Eratosthenes

Comment: Quadratic complexity. Homework presumably, but now you've been given an answer can you explain it?

Comment: @john not true, it's not quadratic.

Comment: @john Less see inner loop control : `i*j<n`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki OK, I wasn't 100% sure, so I left myself a little wiggle room.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2582732/3953764

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Algorithmic_complexity

Comment: Fix your algorithm, since you have small mistake there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner loop iterates a number of times proportional to `n/i` for each iteration of the outer loop. So, the total number of iterations is something like `n/2 + n/3 + … + n/n`. We can factor out the n to get `n * (1/2 + 1/3 + … + 1/n)`. We recognize the thing in parentheses is basically the harmonic series up to term n and the partial sums of the harmonic series have logarithmic asymptotic growth in n (see Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics))).

So, it looks like the total number of iterations of the inner loop increases like `n * log(n)`. Each iteration of the inner loop does constant work and outside the inner loop does constant work per iteration of the outer loop. Thus, we get a total amount of work like `a * n + b * n * log(n)` which is `O(n log n)`.

Now this is probably a little sloppy since it's not technically a "free" operation to multiply two numbers. If we ignore this and assume we're talking about realistic computers where all multiplications take about the same time regardless of size (fixed-size variables) then this is fine. Really, if doing this by hand, you'd probably need to consider the cost of multiplying, which is probably proportional to the logarithm of the size of the numbers. This might add an extra logarithmic term giving something like `O(n log^2 n)` or something. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Step by step mathematical formula:

[image]

Comment: More on harmonic function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40245896/3344832