# Big O Complexity of this double loop

Tags: c++, performance, time-complexity

I have been trying to figure out the Big O Complexity of this code:

```
void findSection(string s)
{
    string start = "abc";
    string end = "xyz";

    int startIndex = s.find(start);
    string tempS;
    while(startIndex<s.size())
    {
        for(int i=startIndex; i<=s.size()-3; i+=3)
        {
            tempS = s.substr(i,3);
            if(tempS==end)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        startIndex = s.find(start,startIndex+3);
    }
}
```

Worse case would be if:

```
s="abcabcabcabc.......
```

Orignally I though the complexity would be O(nlog(n)), but after looking at this link:
[Time Complexity of this double loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40332225/time-complexity-of-this-double-loop)

I came up with the complexity as:

```
i=0 ——>   0,3,6,9,…,b   b
i=3 ——>   3,6,9,…,b     b-3
i=6 ——>   6,9,…,b       b-6
i=9 ——>   9,…,b         b-9
i=b ——>                 b-b

b + (b-3) + (b-6) + ... + (b-b) = _____
```

And now I am thinking it might be O(n^2) but I am not sure. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Time complexity of inner loop will be O(logn) whenever (i = i * constant) after every iteration. In the current scenario you are incrementing i by 3 but worst time complexity of inner loop isn't effected by addition of constant. It will remain O(n).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TDLR: **O(N²)**

Outer loop is N iterations (one iteration for each char in the string).

Inner loop:

A normal inner loop that starts on the index of the outer loop is N/2.  But since it's incremented by 3, It's (N/2)*(1/3). Or simply N/6

N*(N/6) is N²/6.  Hence order of the highest polynomial: **N²**

Answer (score 0):

Big O Time complexity is `O(N*N)`
as you are clearly going through the second loop where the program ends only when it iterates over divider of 3 times.
To be precise , the time complexity is < O(N^2)