# O-notation for j+=i

Tags: c, data-structures, big-o

I need to find the O-notation for the following bit of code:

```
for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
  for(j = 0; j < N; j+=i){
    x+=y;
  }
}
```

I've been able to get it down to O(N*log(N)), but I want to be sure.
Does this kind of function have a name I can look up and research?

Comment: Are you sure you don’t want the outer loop to start from ‘i = 1’?

Answer (score 6):

Your code is O(∞). On the first outer loop, `i` is 0, which means your increment for `j` is 0, and therefore the inner loop becomes an infinite loop when `N > 0`.

Answer (score 5):

**For the case when i starts from 0:**

Your code is O(∞) as explained by ShadowRanger's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46749059/6741053).

**For the case when i starts from 1:**

You can simply use the observation that your actual complexity **f(N)** is bounded by:

```
f(N) <= N/1 + N/2 + N/3 + ... + N/N 

     <= N * (Bound of value of Harmonic Number) 

     < c1 * N * ( log (N) ) i.e. O( N log(N) )
```

To prove that value of [Harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) is `O( log(N) )`, you can use simple calculus. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905118/finding-big-o-of-the-harmonic-series) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Comment: Hey, answering the (probable) real question with facts and stuff! Good show!