# Asymptotic notation of sum 1 / i

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

What is the **asymptotic notation** of

[image]

i.e.

```
sum_(i = 1)^n (1 / i)
```

First of all, this is not a homework. Second, since there is **no formula** to calculate fraction, I don't know how to express this summation with `n` and get the **asymptotic notation**.

That might be `Theta(n)`, but I am **not sure**.

Comment: You're going to need to do your own homework.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding Big O of the Harmonic Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905118/finding-big-o-of-the-harmonic-series).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression

```
sum_(i = 1)^n (1 / i)
```

is the `n-th` [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

From the Wikipedia article:

> The `n-th` **harmonic number** is about **as large** as the **natural logarithm** of `n`. The reason is that the sum is **approximated** by the **integral**:
>
> `int_1^n (1 / x) dx`
>
> whose value is `ln(n)`.

They also give this nice image which shows the correlation:

[image: correlation between harmonic and natural log]

So it is `Theta(log n)`.

See [Finding Big O of the Harmonic Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905118/finding-big-o-of-the-harmonic-series) or [Simple proof of showing the Harmonic number Hn=Θ(logn)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306371/simple-proof-of-showing-the-harmonic-number-h-n-theta-log-n) for details of the proof, it is quite simple.