# Remove all the multiples of a given set of numbers from given range

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, numbers

I am stuck on a problem, where it says, given a number `N` and a set of numbers, `S = {s1,s2,.....sn}` where `s1 < s2 < sn < N`, remove all the multiples of `{s1, s2,....sn}` from range `1..N`

**Example:**

```
Let N = 10
S = {2,4,5}
Output: {1, 7, 9}
Explanation: multiples of 2 within range: 2, 4, 6, 8
             multiples of 4 within range: 4, 8
             multiples of 5 within range: 5, 10
```

I would like to have an algorithmic approach, psuedocode rather than complete solution.

**What I have tried:**

```
(Considering the same example as above) 

 1. For the given N, find all the prime factors of that number.
    Therefore, for 10, prime-factors are: 2,3,5,7
    In the given set, S = {2,4,5}, the prime-factors missing from 
    {2,3,5,7} are {3,7}.  
 2. First, check prime-factors that are present: {2,5}
    Hence, all the multiples of them will be removed 
    {2,4,5,6,8,10}
 3. Check for non-prime numbers in S = {4}
 4. Check, if any divisor of these numbers has already been 
    previously processed.
         > In this case, 2 is already processed.
         > Hence no need to process 4, as all the multiples of 4 
           would have been implicitly checked by the previous 
           divisor.
    If not,
         > Remove all the multiples from this range.
 5. Repeat for all the remaining non primes in the set.
```

Please suggest your thoughts!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to solve it in O(N log(n)) time and O(N) extra memory using something similar to the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

```
isMultiple[1..N] = false

for each s in S:
    t = s
    while t <= N:
        isMultiple[t] = true
        t += s

for i in 1..N:
    if not isMultiple[i]:
        print i
```

This uses O(N) memory to store the `isMultiple` array.

---

The time complexity is O(N log(n)). Indeed, the inner while loop will be performed N / s<sub>1</sub> times for the first element in S, then N / s<sub>2</sub> for the second, and so on.

We need to estimate the magnitude of N / s<sub>1</sub> + N / s<sub>2</sub> + ... + N / s<sub>n</sub>.

N / s<sub>1</sub> + N / s<sub>2</sub> + ... + N / s<sub>n</sub>
 = N * (1/s<sub>1</sub> + 1/s<sub>2</sub> + ... + 1/s<sub>n</sub>) <= N * (1/1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/n).

The last inequality is due to the fact that s<sub>1</sub> < s<sub>2</sub> < ... 
< s<sub>n</sub>, thus the worst case is when they take values {1, 2, .. n}.

However, the harmonic series 1/1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/n is in O(log(n)), (*e.g.* see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905118/finding-big-o-of-the-harmonic-series)), thus the time complexity of the above algorithm is O(N log(n)).

Answer (score 1):

basic solution:

```
let set X be our output set.

for each number, n, between 1 and N:
    for each number, s, in set S:
        if s divides n:
            stop searching S, and move onto the next number,n.
        else if s is the last element in S:
            add n to the set X.
```

you can obviously remove multiples in S before running this algorithm, but I don't think prime numbers are the way to go

Answer (score 1):

Since S is sorted, we can guarantee `O(N)` complexity by skipping elements in S already marked  (http://codepad.org/Joflhb7x):

```
N = 10
S = [2,4,5]
marked = set()
i = 0
curr = 1

while curr <= N:
  while curr < S[i]:
    print curr
    curr = curr + 1

  if not S[i] in marked:
    mult = S[i]

    while mult <= N:
      marked.add(mult)
      mult = mult + S[i]

  i = i + 1
  curr = curr + 1

  if i == len(S):
    while curr <= N:
      if curr not in marked:
        print curr
      curr = curr + 1

print list(marked)
```