# Can anyone explain the steps to calculate the time complexity of this code and what it would be?"

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity

I have a code snippet that I would like to analyze for time complexity. The code is as follows:

```
for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {     
    for (j=1; j<=n; j=j+i) {         
        printf("x");     
    } 
}
```

I would like to know the time complexity of this code

Comment: What do _you_ think the time complexity of this is? Is `n` a constant, or a user input?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I believe Chris was trying to let OP think through the question again and try and get the solution. If n is fixed, ie 5, then the program will not be a function of n. Just thoughts though

Comment: Minor stylistic suggestion as an aside: `j = j + i` == `j += i`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding Big O of the Harmonic Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905118/finding-big-o-of-the-harmonic-series)

Answer (score 2):

The complexity is proportional to the number of Xs you get, which is roughly:

n + n/2 + n/3 + n/4 ... n/n

That is

n ( 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 ... 1/n)

The second term is the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)).  It comes out to about log<sub>e</sub> n, so your total complexity is O(n log n)