# time complexity data structure

Tags: for-loop, data-structures, time, time-complexity

What is time complexity of this code?

I think the answer is *O(n^2)* but I'm not sure about time complexity of the second loop.

```
for (int i=1; i<=n; i++){
    for (int j=1; j<n; j+=i){
        x++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can anyone explain the steps to calculate the time complexity of this code and what it would be?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76001149/can-anyone-explain-the-steps-to-calculate-the-time-complexity-of-this-code-and-w)

Answer (score 1):

Don't just guess - reason and calculate.

It's not going to be obvious at a glance whether O(n^2) is the tightest upperbound or not. You need to calculate exactly. O(n^2) is obviously a correct upperbound, since the inner loop's time of execution is obviously at most `n`, but you might be able to find a tighter bound.

The inner loop (the loop over `j`) executes in its entirety at every iteration of the outer loop (the loop over `i`).

Variable `i` keeps the same value throughout one whole execution of the inner loop.

If `j` increases by `i` at every iteration of the inner loop, and `j` goes from `1` to `n`, what is the time of execution of the inner loop, as a function of both `i` and `n`?

Then you can sum these times over all values of `i`, and this gives you the exact time complexity.

As a big hint: It might not be obvious to you how to simplify this sum into a simple value; but if a teacher gave you this assignment, I'm guessing you must have a theorem somewhere about "harmonic numbers" or "harmonic sums" and this theorem will tell you how to simplify this sum.