# Is the time complexity of this code O(n^2) or O(nlogn)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

```cpp
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
   for (int j = 1; j <= n; j += i) {
       // some code
   }
}
```

The outer loop definitely runs `n` times. In case of the inner loop, assuming n = 8,

| i | j |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ---> ran N times |
| 2 | 1, 3, 5, 7 ---> ran N/2 times |
| 3 | 1, 4, 7 |
| 4 | 1, 5 |
| 5 | 1, 6 |
| 6 | 1, 7 |
| 7 | 1, 8 |
| 8 | 1 |

I am confused whether the complexity should be `logn` or `n` for the inner loop. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: my mistake: i misread !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The outer loop iterates from `i = 1` to `n` with a step size of `1`. Therefore, the outer loop executes `n` times - linear time complexity.

The inner loop iterates from `j = 1` to `n` with a step size of `i`. The step size `i` is dependent on the value of `i` in the outer loop.

As your table indicates;

- When `i` is `1`, the inner loop executes `n` times.
- When `i` is `2`, the inner loop executes `n/2` times.
- When `i` is `3`, the inner loop executes `n/3` times.
- ...
- When `i` is `n`, the inner loop executes `n/n` times, which is `1`.

The sum of these iterations becomes:

```
n + n/2 + n/3 + ... + 1
```

If we factor out *n*, we obtain the harmonic series:

```
1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... 1/n
```

whose time complexity is approximated to `log(n)`. You can see a more detailed explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25905474/12974735

So, in total your code has `O(n log(n))` time complexity.

Comment: I ran an empirical experiment. I wrote a function hsum(n) which calculates the sum n + n/2 + n/3 + ... + n/n.   And for i from 1 to 1000, I compared hsum(i) to i * log(i).  The values are close and grow together.  i log i is the smaller of the two, but the ratio between them slowly grows. It's around 0.92 at 1000, 0.9598952 at 1M,  0.9654264 at 10M.

Comment: I think the total complexity is O(log(n)) not O(n.log(n)) as you don't process the data n times the harmonic series. The harmonic series already takes the 'i' loop into account.

Comment: @JérômeRadix No, it would indeed be *O(n logn)* I think. The code would process *n + n/2 + n/3 + ... + 1* times, which is **not** the harmonic sum. The harmonic sum is *1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/n*, so we factor out *n* and then apply it back. This could be clarified in the answer, which leaves it a little ambiguous.

Comment: @Berthur : thx, I understand now, but the answer says "The sum of these iterations is known as the harmonic series; n + n/2 + n/3 + ... + 1" which is wrong.

Comment: @JérômeRadix Yes it is. Since the answer otherwise seems pretty good, I took the liberty to edit that part for clarity.